# Virtualizing horizontally and vertically for large grid

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to virtualize both horizontally and vertically?

All examples show one or the other.

Imagine a large grid like structure:

1. *n* amount of rows
2. and as many columns as there are hours in one month

At any one point only 4 rows maybe on screen showing only 2 columns (2 hours). Virtualization one way doesn't make sense. This is an up down / left to right scrollable grid.

I ask because I can't for life of me find any examples online? Also I can't find anyone else who has had the same query. Maybe the design in general is wrong or I don't quite know what I'm searching for.

I did think the design maybe wrong i.e. is there a better alternative but I don't think so. This planner-like-grid is required! The only other consideration I had was to dyanmically build pivot pages but this seems messy and won't have the same feel.

Can anyone begin to advise were I might look?

Comment: Can I use a VirtualizingStackPanel, first virtically and then have a VirtualizingStackPanel for each item which virtualizes horizontally? Would Virtualizing still work and would the performance be decent? Again can't find much on this either.

Comment: How will the content be loaded into your design?

Comment: I take back the nested virtualization idea above. Not sure that would work since it wouldn't allow a smooth scrolling action in all directions of the grid, diagonal!!

In terms of data loading. I must be honest I'm not entirely sure. Load so far into the future (24 hours) and as scrolling approaches that 24 hour start buffering into the future again. Whether the data is all loaded/cached/loaded on the fly its the virtualization which I want as it binds. Say it was lots and lots of rectangles in a scrolling panel this would be huge on memory and performance and its this I want to avoid.

Comment: in a situation like this it would seem fit to load your content with swipe gestures, so as their swiping load text and so on...to not have the lag time, i would load all important data(Largest Files) for every load of new content. If that makes sense at least. Reason for that would be so smaller files are loaded at the worst time to load data....depending on what your app is going to be doing you could always use a loading bar...may not be appropriate though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is however the implementation of doing such a thing I am seeking. Not the code, not someone to do it for me, but how that approach of a gesture/scrolling can cause the following: 1. a data refresh 2. some control templates being added as new data is binded 3. possibly old controls being unloaded/resused so the entire control being scrolled stays minimal in memory.

Other that a simple binding of a list. I can't find any complex binding scenarios like this grid.

a data fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether right or wrong, the direction I'm going in is the following. I wanted to post one answer for any one stumbling across the question.

Using a grid, I'm creating a 2 x 2 grid. Top right, bottom left and bottom right will all contain scroll viewers. The scroll viewer in the bottom right when scrolled will dyanmically change the scroll position of the bottom left scroll viewer and top right scroll viewer. Similar scroll top right will dyanmically scroll bottom right, and bottom left will scroll bottom right.

Obviously a lot of scroll viewer bindings but this is one solution which will work in order to give me the planner functionality and layout.

In terms of the virtualization I am dyanmically going to queue controls in order to keep the performance decent, reusing controls where required.

Comment: I know it's been two years from this, but now I have similar problem. You can see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502991/implementing-scrollable-table-on-windows-phone/21621502. Can you please explain a little bit better how this works, maybe show the code?