# Implementing scrollable table on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I need to create an app for TV guide. Requirement is that UI must be a copy of one you can see here: [raspored.bnet.hr](http://raspored.bnet.hr). As you can see, there's a lot of data. So, basically it would be a large scrollable table. Since there is no such UI control as table on Windows Phone, I found out that the best approach would be to create one vertical listbox with horizontal listboxes as its items. This is all ok and I'm able to create it. But, to make it behave like a table I also need to make these horizontal listboxes scroll in sync, not to scroll one row at a time. Then I disabled horizontal scroll on horizontal listboxes, and enabled it on the parent (vertical) listbox and while it gave the result I wanted to achieve one big problem came up - UI virtualization. I know ListBox has UI virtualization enabled by default and I can see it while scrolling on vertical listbox, but when I disable horizontal scroll on horizontal listboxes, performance is really bad, and sometimes there's an OutOfMemoryException. I understand why this happens because when I disabled horizontal scroll, those listboxes didn't know which items are on screen anymore, so the loaded all of them into memory.

What I also tried is to leave scroll on every listbox so they have UI virtualization, and then place ScrollViewer above them. Then I tried to listen on Manipulation events on scrollviewer and progamatically scroll all of the listboxes as needed. This didn't work good, first of all ManipulationDelta event doesn't appear to fire frequently enough to make scrolling smooth, and I think there could be a performance problem with calling ScrollToHorizontalOffset on ~180 listboxes.

I also tried the LongListSelector from WP8 as I read that it has much better UI virtualization and should be used instead of ListBox. The problem with this is that I couldn't make it scroll horizontally. Is it possible at all? I tried to wrap it into ScrollViewer which can scroll horizontally and it's working, but only if I set fixed width on LLS.

I also tried Telerik's RadDataBoundListBox and the problem was similar, I can't get both horizontal and vertical scrolls on the same listbox. So I could only get that each list scrolls on its own.

Can someone tell me if they had similar situation and what would be the best approach to solve this? I believe I'm not the only one that has this requirement to implement large scrollable table.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I'll just inform you that I didn't find a proper way to implement this, instead I've done it in HTML with WebBrowser control. Seems like IE already has UI virtualization implemented so it can work with large pages very well.

Comment: What about just using Grid inside ScrollView?

Comment: OutOfMemoryException. It can't handle so much data since it doesn't have UI virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

May be in your listbox there are images? and Out of memory Execption will occur you can do 2 things:

1. Don't load data in one time use BackgroundWorker
2. Have one local image in the App of the image you are downloading and set it as default image & when you scroll to some 50 values in forward clean the image Url to local and when it comes back give again the image url you want to show .
   Because i have used it to scroll around 20k values.

Comment: There are images in the list, but they are small, about 50 kb each so I don't think they are the biggest problem. The biggest problem as I understand is that one row is so large, with many TextBlocks it takes about 3 MB. And since I cannot get virtualization both vertically and horizontally it has to load entire row in memory. The way I'm trying to go is reduce memory required by UI elements of each item by simplifying them and reducing number of items loaded by VirtualizingStackPanel.

Comment: Have you tested with the Analysis tool of windows phone in that you can find that may be your problem is with Images or GC. 
If your problem is with Images you can go with this method.

Comment: Yes, I've tried also without images, and memory consumption is only insignificantly lower. The problem is that one element of LLS (one row) contains large number of textblocks (about 50) and they consume about 3-4 MB each.

Comment: What you are showing in the textblocks ??
Make them in one.

Comment: One textblock is one TV episode. I will try to make them in one (maybe I already did), but each episode has to be clickable, needs to have border etc. So one row is not just a simple text.